# iPhone echo cancellation, can I disable it?

Tags: iphone, ios4, audio, noise-reduction

I am developing an app that needs to play music while on the phone. The problem is that the iPhone 4 noise cancellation system is canceling my sound and the interlocutor doesn't here anything. I was wondering if it's possible to disable and\or setup that.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There do exist Audio Session APIs to configure some of the SoundProcessing (including echo cancellation).  However, during a phone call on a stock OS iOS device, the audio session is given to the Phone app, and thus all audio and audio control capability is taken away from your app, you have no control over any of it.

Answer (score 1):

No, your app can't do anything during a phone call.